# Pagination vs Bundling in Google Glass Mirror API

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

From what I read in the documentation, bundling allows you to display a sublist of cards once the user clicks on the cover.  Does pagination just display a series of related cards at the top level ("root") timeline?  If so, are there any good use cases for pagination?  I would assume almost all users would prefer that there is a cover for a specific app that they can drill down into rather than have an application litter all of its cards on the root timeline.

Comment: I've been wondering this too.  What is the use case for these two features to be separate?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I thought about this a bit more and it seems that the discerning difference between the two is that pagination is automatic (Glass automatically splits up the timeline item when there's not enough room to display all of the image(s) / text) while bundling happens when you specify a list of items are related by listing the same bundle ID on all of them.  The documentation makes the concept harder to grasp than it really is :(

Comment: So it's a matter of whether or not you know the length of your content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pagination automatically breaks up long content into multiple cards, but only the first card is displayed at the top level of the timeline. If an item needs to be paginated, a "Read more" menu item will be automatically inserted so that the user can read the rest of the pages. You would use this feature when you have free-flowing content like an e-mail message or a news story that you're inserting into the user's timeline. Note that pagination is automatic -- you only insert **one** timeline item.

Bundling is when you insert **multiple** timeline items with the same bundle ID, which causes them to appear as a single item at the top level of the timeline, and tapping it lets the user drill down into the remaining items in the bundle. This is useful, for example, if you need to insert several related but independent items at once without cluttering the user's timeline, like sports scores for several games in the same day.